# Laravel fresh project does not recognize Vite when running npm run dev OR npm run build

Tags: node.js, laravel, vite

I installed new laravel project 'version 10' using this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

then run

```
npm install
```

> npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Aures\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-28T10_25_53_886Z-debug-0.log

This is the Log file content:

```
39 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 5ms
40 timing idealTree:node_modules/undefined Completed in 0ms
41 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 5ms
42 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
43 timing idealTree Completed in 17ms
44 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 18ms
45 timing command:install Completed in 24ms
46 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
46 verbose stack     at [diffTrees] (C:\Users\Aures\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:353:20)
46 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (C:\Users\Aures\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:169:27)
46 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\Aures\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:147:5)
46 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\Aures\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:89:5)
47 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app
48 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
49 verbose node v18.16.0
50 verbose npm  v9.6.5
51 error Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
52 verbose exit 1
53 timing npm Completed in 267ms
54 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1682680248140
55 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:diffTrees 1682680248161
56 verbose code 1
```

So, I add "name" property to `package.json` by `npm init` or add it directly.

package.json before `npm init`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

package.json after `npm init`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "name": "example-app1",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "vite.config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Then I run `npm install` again and this is the result

> up to date in 263ms

But, no package was added to my project files.

The first time I thought that everything is good. So, I run the following command

```
npm run dev
```

ended up with this error (as expected) node_modules folder does not exist.

```
> example-app1@1.0.0 build
> vite build

vite n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

English Translation: vite is not recognized as an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.
```

My node version: v18.16.0
My npm version: 9.6.5

the first time the node version was 16. I supposed that what caused the problem. so, I updated it to 18. but the problem persist.

I tried this also:

```
npm cache clean --force && npm install
```

And because dependencies are for development I tried this also.

```
npm install --include=dev
```

I do the same steps on another PC and everything goes smoothly without any problem.

Comment: You have something wrrong, you have 100% to run `npm install`, but you are running `npm init`, you are either overwritting the `packages.json` or you are in a wrong folder... check that please, you do not have to run `npm init`, you already have the `packages.json`

Comment: yes `npm init` overwrite `packages.json` -I edited the post to showing the difference-. without adding a "name" property to `packages.json` I ended up with this error
`npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.`
I make some changes to the post, It would be great if you check it.

Comment: That error is weird. I am not with a computer roght now (phone), let me try running it stock as you did and I will get back to you. But you should still not run `npm init` nor add a `name` property. It should run as is

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the contents of the .bin directory to see if it is empty or not. If it is, copy the contents from another project.